# Test a string against a RegEx Pattern in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to test a string against a regex 
`^(?:\(|%[0-9]+)(?:\s+|%[0-9]+|\) and+|\) or+|\)+|and|or|\()*$`
I have tested this regex against different scenarios and worked fine for my needs.
I  used http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to test it.
When I try to use it in the javascript it gives me runtime error saying the regular expression is not valid. I am using the following code

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^(?:\(|%[0-9]+)(?:\s+|%[0-9]+|\) and+|\) or+|\)+|and|or|\()*$");
var filterExpress = this.model.FilterExpression();
var result = pattern.test(filterExpress);
```

When I try to use it as below

```
var pattern = /^(?:\(|% [0 - 9]+)(?:\s+ |% [0 - 9]+|\) and+|\) or+|\)+ | and | or|\() * $/;
```

that always returns a false. Please help.

Comment: RegExr uses the actionscript (flash) implementation of Regex. This is not the same as the JS implementation of Regex (or the PERL/PHP implementation of regex). You can use [regex101](http://regex101.com) to change the implementation (check the top where it says PCRE - change that to javascript) and test JS regexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for declaring your regex:

```
re = /^(?:\(|%[0-9]+)(?:\s+|%[0-9]+|\) and+|\) or+|\)+|and|or|\()*$/;
```

OR using `RegExp` object:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^(?:\\(|%[0-9]+)(?:\\s+|%[0-9]+|\\) and+|\\) or+|\\)+|and|or|\\()*$");
```

Remember that you need to double escape in the `RegExp` constructor.

Comment: That is not an unmatched bracket. That is a requirement in my expression. I am matching a string like (%1 and %2). My expression is correct as I have tested it on regex tools, the problem is I am not able to compare my string against in javascript.

Comment: See updated answer. I had posted my answer before question was edited.

Comment: Thanks that works...which characters I need to double escape when writing the pattern in javascript?

Comment: You're welcome. You can use the first form of declaring regex without any double escaping. For the 2nd form when using `RegExp` object you need to double escape every-time backslash (\\) is coming in the regex.